# Map and Filter through array of objects (multi-level)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filter

I am attempting to filter this data to only pull the items where `myData.items.flaggedItem` is `not null`. I have been trying different variations of this, but still no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
ObjectValues.map(objValue => {
  objValue.items?.filter(filteredItems => filteredItems.flaggedItem).map(filteredItems => {
    //where I would think I could print out items filtered
  })
});


"myData":[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "items":[
       {
         "id": "idOne",
         "flaggedItem": null,
       },
       {
         "id": "idTwo",
         "flaggedItem": 1,
       },
   },
   {
     "id": "id2",
     "items":[
       {
         "id": "idThree",
         "flaggedItem": 1,
       },
       {
         "id": "idFour",
         "flaggedItem": 2,
       },
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "idTwo",
        "flaggedItem": null
      },
      {
        "id": "idThree",
        "flaggedItem": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "idThree",
        "flaggedItem": 1
      },
      {
        "id": "idThree",
        "flaggedItem": 2
      }
    ]
  }
];

//iterate through each object
let filteredData = data.map(objValue => {
  //filter the items by checking if flaggedItem is not null
  let filteredItems = objValue.items.filter(items => items.flaggedItem !== null);
  //return a new object with the properties as in the original object
  return { ...objValue, items: filteredItems };
});

console.log(filteredData);
```